# Remove ID's based on their max value with dpylr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5)
time <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

test <- data.frame(value, time, ID)

 value time ID
1  0.00    0  1
2  0.10    0  2
3  0.20    0  3
4  0.40    0  4
5  0.00    1  1
6  0.05    1  2
7  0.05    1  3
8  0.50    1  4
```

I would like to remove all the ID's that never show across the time a value higher than 0.10

my new data.frame should look like this

```
 value time ID
3  0.20    0  3
4  0.40    0  4
7  0.05    1  3
8  0.50    1  4
```

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a group by operation with `any`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(any(value  > 0.1)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  value  time    ID
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0.2      0     3
#2  0.4      0     4
#3  0.05     1     3
#4  0.5      1     4
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `subset` + `ave` to drop those `ID` that have `all` the values less than 0.1.

```
subset(test, !ave(value <= 0.1, ID, FUN = all))

#  value time ID
#3  0.20    0  3
#4  0.40    0  4
#7  0.05    1  3
#8  0.50    1  4
```

and with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .SD[!all(value <= 0.1)], ID]
```